# ansible - get list of all hostnames and corresponding ansible_host values from inventory

Tags: ansible

My inventory looks like this:

```
db0 ansible_host=10.0.0.1
db1 ansible_host=10.0.0.2
app0 ansible_host=10.0.0.3
app1 ansible_host=10.0.0.4
...
```

From this, I need to extract a list like this:

```
- name: db0
  ip: 10.0.0.1
- name: db1
  ip: 10.0.0.2
- name: app0
  ip: 10.0.0.3
- name: app1
  ip: 10.0.0.4
```

I know I can get all hosts using `groups['all']`.

I can also get the `ansible_host` value for each host using `hostvars['<hostname>']['ansible_host']`.

How do I combine this to create the list I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example

```yaml
host_ip: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                  zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                      map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host'))) }}"
```

creates the dictionary

```yaml
  host_ip:
    app0: 10.0.0.3
    app1: 10.0.0.4
    db0: 10.0.0.1
    db1: 10.0.0.2
```

Then, use *dict2items* to create the list

```yaml
host_ip_list: "{{ host_ip|dict2items(key_name='name',
                                     value_name='ip') }}"
```

gives the expected structure

```yaml
  host_ip_list:
  - ip: 10.0.0.1
    name: db0
  - ip: 10.0.0.2
    name: db1
  - ip: 10.0.0.3
    name: app0
  - ip: 10.0.0.4
    name: app1
```

Comment: While this is nice, it's not really the format I need.

Comment: Use *dict2items* to create the list. I added an example.

Comment: Great, this works.